# Difference between xhr.response and xhr.responseText on XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When doing a 'GET' request, `xhr.response` and `xhr.responseText` both return the same value. What's the difference? Is there any?

Answer (score 35):

The `response` is interpreted into a `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob`, `Document`, JavaScript object, or a `DOMString`, depending on the value of `XMLHttpRequest.responseType`. `responseText`, on the other hand is the raw text, and you can handle it however you want. They are very similar in usage though.

1. You can use `response` when you get JSON from the server, and have it translated into a JavaScript object.
2. You can use `responseText` when you don't own the server, and the `responseType` is a format you don't want to use.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest: Look @ the Properties